# error " Undefined function 'data_ref' for input arguments of type 'double'. "

Tags: matlab

my code matlab for denoising EEG artifact show me always this error : "error " Undefined function 'data_ref' for input arguments of type 'double'. "

```
%% Load Reference Data
load data_ref;
data_ref = data_ref(1:data_length)*10/2^15;
data_ref = power_supply_noise_remove(data_ref, Fs);
data_ref = data_ref - mean(data_ref);
data_ref = [data_ref data_ref];**
```

the error is line 26:

> Undefined function 'data_ref' for input arguments of type 'double'.
>   Error in art_emd_ica (line 26) data_ref = data_ref(1:data_length)*10/2^15;

Comment: Okay, so `load data_ref` did not load a variable called `data_ref`... assuming that's what you expected to happen.

Comment: i changed  load ('data_ref.mat');  and its still the same error

Comment: When you loaded the file from the command line (you did that, didn't you?) were there any variables added to the workspace? If not, is the file in the current search path? If there were, what variables were there? Was `data_ref` among them?

Comment: yes the data_ref.mat is the file contain EEG signal and on the current path

Comment: no any other variables added to the works space

Comment: If no variables were added, then there are no variables in the `.mat` file.

Comment: data_ref.mat is the file contain EEG signal

Comment: i dont understand about the variables added !

Comment: After you `load('data_ref.mat')`, do you have a variable in your workspace called `data_ref`? Type `whos data_ref`.

Comment: i understand sir ,, when i type whos data_ref  nothing is happened and i haven't data_ref in the workspace

Comment: Then that `.mat` file does not load the variable `data_ref`. You'll have to find out what variables it *does* load.

Comment: i changed FileData = load('data_ref.mat');
data_ref = FileData.data_ref(1:data_length)*10/2^15;   but it show new error     'Reference to non-existent field 'data_ref'.

Error in art_emd_ica (line 26)
data_ref = FileData.data_ref(1:data_length)*10/2^15;

Comment: Then the `data_ref.mat` file contains no variable called `data_ref` and, therefore, it doesn't exist no matter how to try to `load` the file.  Something went wrong when the file was created if you expect there to be a variable called `data_ref`, and we can't help you with that.